# Convertir datos de un archivo txt a una matriz

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

tengo el siguiente problema tengo un archivo de texto con estos datos

```
xexxxxxxxx
xxxxoooxos
eooooxooox
xxoxxxoxxx
xxoxxxxxxx
```

y necesito transformarlo a una matriz en python.

Tengo el siguiente código pero me lo transforma todo los datos a tipo list por lo que no los puedo manipular para hacer las validaciones que necesito[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca tu código como texto. Como imagen, habría que retipear entero el código.

Comment: Y eso de `xexxxxxxxx` `xxxxoooxos`, etc ¿qué es exactamente? ¿son números? ¿letras? ¿cómo están separados? y ¿cómo los quieres al final? Ten en cuenta que una matriz no es más que una lista cuyos elementos son listas.

Comment: Las matrices se crean de esta manera `np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')`. Como puedes ver hay un espacio entre los números, no es lo mismo 1 2 que 12. ¿Cómo se puede construir una matriz desde tu archivo si no tiene espacios? Claro que podemos añadir los espacios, pero ¿cómo hacerlo en los puntos correctos?

Comment: Esto te dará una estructura más similar a la necesaria para construir una matriz `datos = ''.join(archivo.readlines()).replace('\n',';')`

Answer (score 0):

En respuesta a tu pregunta. Una forma de convertir los datos de un txt a una matriz es la siguiente:

txt 1

```
1 23 45
2 4 6
3 6 8
```

txt 2

```
12345
24600
36800
```

#### Script

```
import numpy as np

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    datos = ''.join(f.readlines()).replace('\n',';')

m = np.matrix(datos)
print(m)
```

#### Devuelve

1

```
[[ 1 23 45] 
 [ 2  4  6] 
 [ 3  6  8]]
```

2

```
[[12345]
 [24600]
 [36800]]
```